# What's the meaning of "to your halls and bowers"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> "O welcome, father dear, **to your halls and bowers**, and welcome to you,
>   my new mother, for all that's here is yours" said Princess Margaret.

This is from a English fairly tale "The Laidly Worm of Spindrestone Heugh".She said this at her castle gate when her stepmother came there for the first time. Could you teach me?

I come across it now. Wouldn't it be "welcome to your halls and bowers"?

Comment: Does your dictionary tell you what the noun _bower_ means?

Comment: A dictionary says it means "the shade of a tree".

Comment: Most dictionaries define it more or less as _garden,_ although here it could also mean _private apartment._ See [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bower). Be sure to consult more than one dictionary!

Comment: Does it mean "thank you for coming to your halls and bowers" and is it said to her father?

Comment: The father is addressed, but no thanks are offered. Does your dictionary also define the word _welcome?_

Comment: It would mean "reception".

Comment: It is used here as an interjection. See the first entry at [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/welcome?s=t)

Comment: The sentence can be rephrased, e.g., "Father dear, welcome to your halls and bowers. My new mother, welcome to you, for (= because) all that's here is yours."

Answer (score 2):

The context is she is meeting her father at the front gate of their house and is welcoming him home

> to your halls and bowers

to the "*halls*" of his house and his "lands" ("*bowers*")

[image]